# Select data from table making records with certain fields appear first in the resultset

Tags: mysql

I have a reviews table with from_id and to_id fields for the users involved. I want to know if theres a way in MySQL to make that the reviews made by a certain user appear on top of all other reviews regardless of the ORDER in the SELECT statement.

Is it possible or would it be better to just fetch the records and then format the response?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The approach I took for the solutions was actually really simple:  

Here we're fetching all the reviews for user 2, as viewed by user 1  
    <!-- language: lang-sql -->
    SELECT * FROM reviews Review
    INNER JOIN users User ON User.id = Review.`to_id`
    INNER JOIN preferences Preference ON Preference.user_id = User.id
    WHERE Review.to_id = 2 
    ORDER BY Review.from_id = 1 DESC, Review.created DESC

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual column for all and assign 1 to it for that specific user (and 0 for the others) and add this column name at the beginning of your `ORDER BY` statement so you will have your order the way you declared but that specific user will be on top.

Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion dude, I ended up solving it in a really straight forward way 

ORDER BY Review.from_id = {theViewerUser} DESC, Review.created DESC